# Pandas series.astype('float'), setting np.na to cells raising error

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to cast my series to float so that I can round it, but some times there are string values in between the numerical values. How can I do the following

```
series = pd.Series(data=[0.32, 0.99, 1.23, "simernes", 3.50])
series = series.astype('float')
series = series.round(1)
```

, 
setting any cells that were strings to `np.na`, so that I can drop them with `.dropna()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`:

```
series = pd.to_numeric(series, errors='coerce').dropna().round(1)
print (series)
0    0.3
1    1.0
2    1.2
4    3.5
dtype: float64
```